# Select2 Initialization Callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Question related to [ivaynberg/select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) jQuery library.

Is it possible to do a function callback once a select2 is initialized or rendered? If so, how?

By looking at the documentation, the closest thing to doing this is using the event `select2-loaded`. However, it is fired when the query gets loaded but not select2 getting initialized.

I'm using a `select` element.

What I'm trying to achieve is adding a custom class to `.select2-chosen` upon initializing the form field based on the default value that's already set. There's no problem with changing the class of `.select2-chosen` on change of the select2 field.

Comment: read about `query function` [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't work with `select` element which happens to be the element that I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm over-thinking too much. Apparently, I can just do whatever I want to do after I run `$.select2()`.

Eg.

```
$('#select2').select2();
$('#select2').find('.select2-chosen').addClass('color-white');
```

Comment: Bear in mind that you can only target elements that are rendered during initialization. It seems obvious, but several parts of the select (e.g. the option list) are not inserted into the DOM on init thus cannot be targeted.

Answer (score 4):

Select2 does not have a delay between the init event and the rendering.  That means, you can execute your actions immediately after initializing.

```
$("select").select2();
$("select").trigger("my-body-is-ready");
```